# Wordpress Password Page - Wrong Password Message Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress

// -----------------------------------------------------------------#
//The password you have entered is invalid.- NOT WORKING

//(When wrong password is entered)On my password protected page when you enter the wrong password, I am trying to show a message. I think the issue is with the cookie but not sure. Please look at code and here is the page. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. The code below is on functions.php 
PLEASE SHOW WHERE THERE IS AN ERROR- So I can copy and paste to correct... Thanks!

// -----------------------------------------------------------------#

function my_password_form() {
         global $post;

```
     $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );

     $passwordProtectedPageURL = 'https://host.561websitedesign.com/~alto/suppliers/';
     $wrongPassword = ' ';


     if( ( sanitize_text_field( $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] ) === $passwordProtectedPageURL ) && ! isset ( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] )){
          $wrongPassword = '<span style="color:#00000;font-weight:bold;">The password you have entered is invalid.</span>';
     }


     $form = '<form class="protected-post-form" action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post">
' . __( "<h3><strong>Please enter password to access Q-Notes</strong></h3><h1>&nbsp;</h1>" ) . '
<label class="pass-label" for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Supplier Login" ) . '" />
</form><p>' . $wrongPassword . '</p>';

     return $form;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );
```

Comment: Code dumps don't help you or the community get to a resolution. See: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what do u mean?  What do u need to help me?

Comment: So, I should begin with - this definitely isn't the best way, it may not always work - it is more of a hack than anything. However, I could not find anything else that works via Google-fu searching ... and I'm guessing you're in the same boat?

Quick overview, on WordPress if you use the Password Protect Page feature, it adds a form to the page that passes the data to this page: wp-login.php?action=postpass.

Comment: Upon correct password input, a cookie is generated and the user is redirected back to the page. The content is outputted if the cookie is set.

What happens if the user enters the wrong password? Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears it just redirects the user back to the page without the cookie.

There we have the answer ... we have to check for the HTTP Referral and whether the cookie is set or not. Throw the following function and filter into your WordPress themes functions.php file.  Please help I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic isn't right.

If the cookie is set when this function is called, that means the hash didn't match so it's an incorrect password.

```
function my_password_form() {
    global $post;

    $attempted     = $_SESSION['pass_attempt'] ?: false;
    $label         = 'pwbox-' . ( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $wrongPassword = '';

    // If cookie is set password is wrong.
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] ) && $attempted !== $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] ) {
        $wrongPassword = '<span style="color:#00000;font-weight:bold;">The password you have entered is invalid.</span>';
        // Store attempted password for comparison.
        // So we can show invalid password message only once.
        $_SESSION['pass_attempt'] = $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ];
    }

    $form = '<form class="protected-post-form" action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post">
    ' . __( '<h3><strong>Please enter password to access Q-Notes</strong></h3><h1>&nbsp;</h1>' ) . '
    <label class="pass-label" for="' . $label . '">' . __( 'Password:' ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( 'Supplier Login' ) . '" />
    </form><p>' . $wrongPassword . '</p>';

    return $form;
}
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'my_password_form' );

add_action(
    'wp_loaded',
    function() {
        if ( isset( $_COOKIE[ 'wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH ] ) ) {
            // Start session to compare pass hashs.
            session_start();
        }
    }
);
```

EDIT

To show the invalid password message only once I have added some session code to compare the password hash to see if its a new attempt.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I truly appreciate it. Here is the page: host.561websitedesign.com/~alto/suppliers  Can you add something to the code for the cookie so if the page refreshes it deletes the cookie?  (will that effect if someone is logged in and refreshes the page?  Thanks again!

Comment: So when I refresh the page the message currently stays there  I would like it to disappear.  If I delete the cookie manually from browser it goes away.  Can you add code to remove that cookie?  So when I refresh the page the message is gone

Comment: I added the code to remove the cookie but the message is still there.... do you know why that would be?

Comment: I think we need to unset the cookie then redirect to this page: https://host.561websitedesign.com/~alto/suppliers/    ???

Comment: I added the code to remove the cookie but the message is still there.... do you know why that would be?  I think we need to unset the cookie then redirect to this page: host.561websitedesign.com/~alto/suppliers ???  I truly appreciate your help!  Thank you!

Comment: Ah yeah, that's a headers already sent error. I have updated my answer to use a session to store the previously attempted password and compare it.